# Use of "relax" as noun

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I looked up *relax* in various English dictionaries and it is always listed as a verb only, the noun being *relaxation*. However in my mother tongue (Italian) *relax* is normally used as a noun. Is this just one more case of misusing a foreign term or are there situations where it is possible to use *relax* as a noun in English too?

Comment: La lingua italiana e quella inglese divergono in questo caso, come in altri. Per noi 'relax' e' un sostantivo, per loro no. Loro direbbero "the relaxation is often need ...", noi invece diciamo "il relax e' spesso necessario ..."

Comment: Dimenticavo! La tua domanda e' interessante: quindi +1.

Comment: I thought so, but "relaxation" sounds a bit odd to me. However, shouldn't your sentence be "relaxation is often needed..."? Maybe you just misspelt a couple of words when typing. Thank you for your reply and your appreciation

Comment: Yes, you are right; but with my BlackBerry I am not able to write better. Goodnight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's strictly a verb.  "I'm relaxing", "you should relax", "he relaxed", whatever.  Saying "I'm having a relax" would typically be regarded as an invalid [nouning](http://arnoldzwicky.wordpress.com/category/morphology/conversion/nouning/).

Comment: So you're telling me that I should use the term as a verb only, and that under no circumstances is it to be used as a noun. Thanks

Comment: @Paola: Right.  Sorry for the confusing answer pre-edit; I partially misread your question the first time through.

Comment: -But only as an INTRANSITIVE verb. A favorite item of Chinglish (I'm an ESL teacher) is to use it as a transitive verb, as in "After studying hard all day, I like to play basketball to relax myself."

Comment: Not so. Transitively, you can *relax your grip*, for example.

Comment: Or, if you're excessively uptight about obscure rules of grammar, you may be advised to *relax your sphincter*.

Comment: Thank you to all of you. It was interesting to learn about phrases I had never heard before; however, they all relate to the term as a verb, whereas my curiosity was about a possible "relax" noun.